# Troubleshooting failed API Certification

Tags: docusignapi

I have been unable to promote one of my integrator keys to production for the past few days.

I have enabled logging and can verify that I have 20+ consecutive error free API calls. Unfortunately, the review results don't give many details.

"Please ensure you have 20 or more consecutive error-free API transactions." I do.

"Verify that your transactions comply with API rules and limits." I believe am in compliant. I am not making over 1,000 api requests per hour. I am not exceeding 1 GET request per 15 minutes.

Per the documentation I've read, I feel that my integrator key should pass the review.

I am at a loss for how else I can troubleshoot the issue. Does anyone have any suggestions? Anything I may have overlooked? Are there other logs I should be looking at?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Sounds more like a question for the product company's support team.

Comment: @stakx I agree. I reached out to them first and they instructed me to post on StackOverflow. I was hoping someone ran into a similar issue and could share some insight.

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend reaching out to go-live@docusign.com and inquire about your Certification. Be sure to include your integrator key.

Comment: Thanks. I sent them an email as well. I'll update this thread with feedback from them. I'm still hopeful someone on SO has run into a similar issue and has some suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

I was counting the wrong actions in my logs. While reviewing the logs, I was counting all of the actions that were made via the Docusign UI. I should have only been counting the PostEnvelope action based on my workflow.

I went through and made 20+ calls to PostEnvelope and I'm happy to say that my integrator key is now pending approval.